# Xamarin Android Replace Default Dialer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to make a custom calling dialer for android on Xamarin, my app should have calling functions, it will replace the default dialer of android and it will call by it self, and not open the default dialer, it will have custom ui to make or receive calls, I searched on internet and found code of: https://github.com/arekolek/simple-phone but its not in c#, I want to implement this simple phone in Xamarin android c#, can anyone help me making this type of app in Xamarin android C#?

Comment: The phone is built with minSdkVersion 23 which is the Minimum Android version (also known as minSdkVersion ) is the oldest version of the Android OS. See example of c# code at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows

Comment: this link does not have the code for my problem

Comment: You are calling a Android method using a bat file and now want to use c# to call same method.  The link shows how to call Android method from c#.  Yes it is not exactly the same method you need, but very similar.